# Symfony2 (Doctrine): Adding non-existent row with M:M relations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities E1 & E2 with ManyToMany relation and linking table for it. Everything is fine until I'm trying add to E1 element of E2 that doesn't exist. For example, E2 is Tag entity. And user puts a couple of tags via form. How to add non-existent tags in E2 before persisting them to E1?

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I've updated my entity according to @Axxiss answer. It *does* persist new tags automaticly but it also persists old tags again. All I whant is if I have a tag with name 'tag1' it shouldn't be added in tags table again.

Comment: What do you mean with "no existent"? You mean it is created but not persisted yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `cascade` annotation to tag field inside E1.

Inside E1 you will have something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="e1_has_tags",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="e1_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
private $tags;
```

Check [Transitive persistence / Cascade Operations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

If you want to add a tag only one time you have two options:

1. Do it on the controller before persisting the entity
2. Do it directly on the Entity

On both cases you need to query by the tag name, if the tag already exist replace it with the Tag found.

Comment: Okay it does persist new tags now. But it persist it for many times. I've updated my question, please, look at it.

Comment: And also you missed two closing parenthesis in 'JoinColumn' :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want unique Tags you need to check if they exists before persist them.

Comment: Okay, I'v converting string 'tag1, tag2, tag3' to ArrayCollection of Tag objects via dataTransformer. Where exactly I should place the query which checks tags for existence? In datatransformer itself of somewhere else?

Comment: The best place to put your queries is inside a Repository class